# Can I stack objects in a QGraphicsScene in an arbitrary order?

Tags: c++, qt

So here is my issue:

I have a scene, with objects A and B in it.

I add object C, as A's child, and D, as B's child.

I want to see both children on top of both parents, that is I want C in front of A and B even though A is behind B.

Is it possible without losing the inheritance?

Comment: No there is no ready solutions. One of workarounds is C as child of B then monitor A and B position changes and recalculate C position.

Comment: Yeah that is what I would have liked to avoid, thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may cause you other issues, but you could take a look at not using the GraphicsItem parenting system.

That leaves with two options: -

1) Handle parenting yourself, which means that each item's Qt parent is the GraphicsScene, allowing the use of setZValue. You will have to then handle transformation and translation of items relative to the parent.

2) Use QGraphicsItemGroup, which may allow calling setZValue on the group's items, as expected, but should handle moving items as a group, rather you having to manually translate and transform child items. I've not tried this myself, but should be simple enough to test this.

In the past, I've used the first method, which does work, but involves writing a lot of code that Qt normally gives you via the parenting system.